# What is the adapter class of a resource selected in the classpath libraries in the eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Use the following code to get the path of a resource(a jar) selected in the "Referenced libraries" or in the "JRE System Library". But it's not a adapter of "org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource", so it's failed.
So what is the adapter class of this resource?

```java
private String getPathOfSelectedResource(ISelection selection) {
    IAdaptable target = (IAdaptable) ((IStructuredSelection) selection).getFirstElement();
    IResource resource = null;
    if (target instanceof IResource) {
        resource = (IResource) target;
    }
    if (resource == null) {
        resource = target.getAdapter(IResource.class);
    }
    if (resource != null) {
        return resource.getLocation().toOSString();
    }
    return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be an `org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaElement`.

Actually it will implement `IPackageFragmentRoot` but I don't think there is an adapter registered for that.

Comment: thx.
It's an adapter. Get it by 'getAdapter(IPackageFragmentRoot.class)'.